# Column I've created is apparently "undefined"?

Tags: r, dataframe, undefined

My code is as below. I have created a column "degree" based on another column which contains integers from 1 to 5.

My code below seems to work because the column has been created sucessfully. However, when I call any code based on the "degrees" column I get NULLL
str(my_data$degree)

```
my_data %>%
mutate(degree = case_when(edcat > 3 ~ "1",                                 
 edcat <=3 ~ "0") )
```

This is what I get when I use "degree" in any code despite the fact I can see the column has been sucessfully created:

```
Error in [.data.frame(my_data, , "degree"): undefined columns selected
Traceback:

1. factor(my_data\[, "degree"\])
2. my_data\[, "degree"\]
3. [.data.frame(my_data, , "degree")
4. stop("undefined columns selected")
```

Comment: have you assigned the mutated data back to `my_data`? it should be `my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(...)`

Comment: Yes. Beginner's error to not save the output in a new df or assign to same data frame after operation. While testing the console will give right output but won't prompt you to save it.

Comment: Hi @AdroMine I have now tried that but it still isn't working. I'm relatively new to R.  'my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(degree =
                     case_when(edcat > 3 ~ "1", 
                               edcat <=3 ~ "0")
)'

Comment: Hi @anuanand apologies, yes I'm a relative beginner. Could you please advise on code to achieve this?

Comment: Detailed answer with sample data provided. Please accept and i would advise to study books like r4ds by Hadley to get good grasp of dplyr and basics.

Comment: Thanks a mill i'm under pressure that was a great help, looks like I understood it find but had some indention or something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to update(overwrite) a data frame with new calculation simply use `<-` like for a variable. However, its better to save in a new df to check the result and keep copy of original (for a beginner to compare input and output)
here I save it in my_result. Or instead use `my_data <-`

```
my_result<- my_data %>%
mutate(degree = case_when(
 edcat > 3 ~ "1",                                 
 edcat <=3 ~ "0"))
```

Or if you are using same df in next processes:

```
my_data<- my_data %>%
    mutate(degree = case_when(
     edcat > 3 ~ "1",                                 
     edcat <=3 ~ "0"))
```

with sample data for edcat :

```
my_data <- data.frame('edcat'= c(1,2,3,5,6,8))
my_data <- my_data%>%mutate(degree = case_when(
  edcat > 3 ~ "1",                                 
  edcat <=3 ~ "0"))

my_data

  edcat degree
1     1      0
2     2      0
3     3      0
4     5      1
5     6      1
6     8      1
```

Now you can use it any way say count of degrees:

```
my_data%>%group_by(degree)%>%summarise(N=n())
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  degree     N
  <chr>  <int>
1 0          3
2 1          3
```

But all this is basic. Please check good resources to learn dplyr like Hadley Wickams R 4 Data Science